# Couldn't manipulate Images.find() in CollectionFS for MeteorJS app

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor, image-upload

My app is sort of like TelescopeJS, but a lot simpler. I'm trying to echo the particular image that has been added in the post-adding form which takes an input of the name of the post, picture, categories and description. It has 2 collections, one for Articles and the other for Images (NOT a mongo collection, it's an FS collection.) The articles collection stores the name,description and category name and the other one stores image. **My Problem is: ** in the FS collection doc, the loop

```
{{#each images}}
    <img src="{{this.url}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" />
{{/each}}
```

Where images: returns Images.find({}) and my articles code is :

```
{{#each articles}}
    <li style="margin-right: 1%;">{{>article}}</li>  
{{/each}}
```

Where articles: returns Articles.find({})

MY articles template HAS the images loop and this causes ALL THE IMAGES in the collection to be shown in one post. I just want specific images to be shown for the specific post.

These are the events:

```
'change .img': function(event, template) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        //Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
      });
    });
  },
    'click .save':function(evt,tmpl){
        var description = tmpl.find('.description').value;
        var name = tmpl.find('.name').value;
        var date=new Date();
        var cat = tmpl.find('.selectCat').value;

        Articles.insert({
            description:description,
            name:name,
            time:date.toLocaleDateString()+' at '+date.toLocaleTimeString(),
            author:Meteor.userId(),
            userEmail:Meteor.user().username,
            category:cat,

        });
    }

   <template name="article">

     {{#each images}}
        <img src="{{this.url}}" alt="" class="thumbnail" />
        {{/each}}
    Here goes the {{name_of_post}}
    Here {{the_category}}
    Here {{the_description}}

    </template>
```

So what happens is, all the images that I've uploaded so far shows in one post and all the posts' picture looks the same. Help please!

Comment: Create good publish function to return only images for specific post

Comment: Do you have an images helper written? How are you passing the images collection to your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that [fsFile support Metadata](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#add-custom-metadata-to-a-file-before-inserting) so maybe you don't need the `Articles Collection`

So we can make a new `eventHandler`.

```
'click .save':function(evt,tmpl){
        var description = tmpl.find('.description').value,
            file = $('#uploadImagePost').get(0).files[0], //here we store the current file on the <input type="file">
            name = tmpl.find('.name').value,
            date=new Date(),
            cat = tmpl.find('.selectCat').value,
            fsFile = new FS.File(file); // we create an FS.File instance based on our file
          fsFile.metadata = {  //this is how we add Metadata aka Text to our files
                   description:description,
                   name:name,
                   time:date.toLocaleDateString()+' at '+date.toLocaleTimeString(),
                  author:Meteor.userId(),
                  userEmail:Meteor.user().username,
                  category:cat, 
                      }
          Images.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
          if(!err){
            console.log(result) // here you should see the new fsFile instance
            }
       });
    }
```

This is how our new event will look, now our `.save` button insert everything on the same collection.

This is how we can access to the `FS.File` instances fields using the keyword `'metadata.fieldName'`.

For example.

```
Teamplate.name.helpers({
  showCategory:function(){
    // var category = Session.get('currentCategory') you can pass whatever data 
    // you want here from a select on the html or whatever.
   //lets say our var its equal to 'Music'
    return Images.find({'metadata.category':category});
  } 
})
```

Now we use that helper on the `html` like any normal collection

```
<template name="example">
  {{#each showCategory}}
    Hi my category is {{metadata.category}} <!-- we access the metadata fields like any normal field on other collection just remember to use the 'metadata'keyword -->
    This is my image <img src="{{this.url}}" >
  {{/each}}
</template>
```